# inserting an element in a linked list

Tags: c

Considering a linked list containing five elements.
1,2,3,4,5 a no '7' is to be inserted after two. we will have an head pointing to the first element of the linked list and ptr at the last. while inserting an element before 3 we will loop through the linked list starting from head to last and we will introduce another pointer(prev) to hold the previous pointers address.ptr will point to the current node and if a matching data is found(3) then we have to include the new node between 2 and 3.
We can do it as we have previous pointer.How to do it without using a previous pointer.

EDITED:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct list
{
    int data;
    struct list* link;
};

struct list *head=NULL;
struct list *tail=NULL;

void createList(int value);
void displayList(struct list* head_node);
void insertNewNode();
int value;


int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
     printf("\nEnter the data to be added into the list:\n");
     scanf("%d",&value);
     createList(value);
    }
    printf("\nCreated Linked list is\n");
    //displayList(head);
    printf("\nInsert a node\n");
    insertNewNode();
    displayList(head);
    return 0;
}
void insertNewNode()
{
    int val;
    struct list* ptr=NULL,*new_node,*prev=NULL;
    new_node = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    printf("Enter the data to be inserted!");
    scanf("%d",&val);

    for(ptr=head;ptr;ptr=ptr->link)
    {
        if(ptr->data == 3)
        {
          printf("Found");
          new_node->data = val;
          prev->link=new_node;
          new_node->link = ptr;
        }
        prev = ptr;
    }
}
void createList(int value)
{
    struct list *newNode;
    newNode = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    //tail = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    newNode->data = value;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else 
    {
        tail->link = newNode;
    }
    tail = newNode;
    tail->link = NULL;
}
void displayList(struct list *head_node)
{
    struct list *i;
    for(i=head;i;i=i->link)
    {
        printf("%d",i->data);
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Rather than trying to **describe** your current code, why not just post some **actual** code?

Comment: @Oli:I have posted the code here.The code posted will not be of good standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void insertNewNode()
{
    int val;
    struct list* ptr=NULL,*new_node;
    new_node = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    printf("Enter the data to be inserted!");
    scanf("%d",&val);

    for(ptr=head;ptr;ptr=ptr->link)
    {
        if(ptr->data == 2)
        {
          printf("Found");
          new_node->data = val;
          new_node->link = ptr->link;
          ptr->link = new_node;
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
This is probably what you want:

```
void insertNewNode()
{
    int val;
    struct list* ptr=NULL,*new_node;
    new_node = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    printf("Enter the data to be inserted!");
    scanf("%d",&val);

    for(ptr=head;ptr->link;ptr=ptr->link)
    {
        if(ptr->link->data == 3)
        {
          printf("Found");
          new_node->data = val;
          new_node->link = ptr->link;
          ptr->link = new_node;
        }
    }
}
```

Here:

```
if(ptr->link->data == 3)
```

you simply look ahead to check if next node has value that you need.

Comment: Thanks develerx but this is a search to be inserted after 2.but how to do it for a search to be inserted before 3 and without using prev pointer.

Comment: Thanks develrex.It was what absolutely i wanted. I was breaking my head to find out this simple concept.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call `curr` the pointer at the current element, `next` the pointer at the next element, and `value` the number stored. 
Traverse the list until `curr.value == 2`, now just create a `new_node` with `new_node.value = 7` and set `new_node.next = curr.next` and `curr.next = new_node`